# convolution with mars mips

Tags: assembly, mips, sobel

i've been trying to implement a convulsion matrix using mips mars. and i've been having some issues generating it.
So what i've got is this, i can open a image file (512x512) convert it to grayscale and then when i try to apply the convulsion i only get a black square:
here's the whole program:

```
.data

 #uncoment
 buffer: .space 786432 # buffer para imagens para 512x512
 bufferGray: .space 262144 # buffer para imagens cinza 512 x 512
 #

#uncoment after 32x32
bufferSobelH: .space 262144 #array sobel horizontal
bufferSobelV: .space 262144 #array sobel Vertical
bufferSomaSobel: .space 262144 #array Somas sobel
bufferFinal: .space 262144 #array final
#


#Arrays Sobel
SobellV: .byte 1,2,1,0,0,0,-1,-2,-1 #Sobel Vertical
SobellH: .byte 1,0,-1,2,0,-2,1,0,-1 #Sobel Horizontal


.text
    main:
#funcao para efectuar a convolution
#argumentos $a0 array de origem escala cinzentos
#argumentos $a1 array de destino ou o sobel horizontal ou vertical
#argumentos $a2 array sobel a usar
la $a0,bufferGray #carrega o endereco buffer imagem em cinzento
la $a1,bufferSobelH # carrega o endereco do buffer para conter o sobel horizontal
la $a2, SobellH #carrega o array sobel horizontal
jal convolution
nop 

jal write_gray_image
nop
jal SafeExit
nop


#funcao para efectuar a convolution
#argumentos $a0 array de origem escala cinzentos
#argumentos $a1 array de destino ou o sobel horizontal ou vertical
#argumentos $a2 array sobel a usar
#argumentos $a3 contador
convolution:
addi $sp,$sp,-4 
sw $ra,0($sp)
addi $a0,$a0,512 #incrementa uma linha
addi $a3,$a3,-512 #retira 512 ao valor do contador para eliminar a linha 
jal filter
nop 


filter:

blt $a3,512,endsobel
nop

#carrega os bytes matrix cinzento
lbu $t0,0($a0)#carrega o valor  da escala de cinzentos
#
#carrega o centro da matrix
lbu $t1,4($a2)
#

#multiplica cada byte(componente) pelo valor da matrix
mul $s0,$t0,$t1
#

#########################################################
#carrega o valor da matrix a direita
lbu $t0,1($a0)
lbu $t1,5($a2)
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2


#########################################################

#########################################################
#carrega o valor da matrix a esquerda
lbu $t0,-1($a0)#o valor da matrix a esquerda
lbu $t1,3($a2)
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2
#########################################################


#sobe uma linha
add $a0,$a0,-512
#

#carrega os bytes matrix cinzento
lbu $t0,0($a0)#carrega o valor  da escala de cinzentos
#
#carrega o centro da matrix
lbu $t1,1($a2)
#

#multiplica cada byte(componente) pelo valor da matrix
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2

#

#########################################################
#carrega o valor da matrix a direita
lbu $t0,1($a0)
lbu $t1,2($a2)
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2


#########################################################

#########################################################
#carrega o valor da matrix a esquerda
lbu $t0,-1($a0)#o valor da matrix a esquerda
lbu $t1,0($a2)
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2
#########################################################
#desce 2 linhas
add $a0,$a0,1024
#
#carrega os bytes matrix cinzento
lbu $t0,0($a0)#carrega o valor  da escala de cinzentos
#
#carrega o centro da matrix
lbu $t1,7($a2)
#

#multiplica cada byte(componente) pelo valor da matrix
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2

#

#########################################################
#carrega o valor da matrix a direita
lbu $t0,1($a0)
lbu $t1,8($a2)
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2


#########################################################

#########################################################
#carrega o valor da matrix a esquerda
lbu $t0,-1($a0)#o valor da matrix a esquerda
lbu $t1,6($a2)
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
add $s0,$s0,$t2
#########################################################
#sobe uma linha
add $a0,$a0,512
#
sra $s0,$s0,2
abs $s0, $s0
sb $s0,0($a1)

addi $a0,$a0,1
addi $a1,$a1,1
addi $a3,$a3,-1


beq $zero,$zero,filter
nop




endsobel:

 #exit here
lw $ra,0($sp) #exit sobel 
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra
nop
```

Comment: That's pretty long to expect somebody to read the whole thing. Perhaps you could take a little time to cut all all but the essentials.

Comment: cleaned it up a bit...maybe better to understand now

Comment: If your program does not work *you* need to debug it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging